# Can I automatically apply a different paragraph style to all paragraphs beginning with a specific character style?

Tags: adobe-indesign, paragraph-styles, grep, character-styles

I'm laying out a very long encyclopedia which has lots of entries. The title of each article is inline with the first paragraph (each entry has multiple paragraphs), but does have a character style applied.

If I can apply a paragraph style to each of those opening paragraphs, I can use that to space out the articles, rather than manually applying the style approximately 5000 times. Can anyone suggest how that might be possible please?

edit: Sorry, I should have specified, this is InDesign with linked text frames throuh 450 pages

Comment: What app are you using?

Comment: I'm sorry, this is InDesign

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Enter *Edit > Find/Change* and choose the *Text* tab.
- Make sure that the *Find what* and *Change to* fields are empty.
- Set *Search* to *Document*.
- Click the *Find Format* field and choose the character style used for the titles.
- Click the *Change Format* and choose the paragraph style you want to apply to each opening paragraph.
- Click *Change All*.

[image]

Comment: That's brilliant, thank you, I had no idea that InDesign would be able to apply that change to the whole paragraph, it worked perfectly.

Comment: Glad to help. Yes, it works because a paragraph can only have one paragraph style applied. So if you change the paragraph style of part of a paragraph you force the whole paragraph to have that paragraph style.