# InDesign Create Table of Contents based on character style?

Tags: adobe-indesign, paragraph-styles, character-styles, table-of-contents

I'm creating a small dictionary to accompany a new project and in it I have things formatted where the paragraph style is just my generic Body Copy style but the defined term itself is its own character style.

For instance:
"**Term** - Definition of term goes here."

So in that example, the entire line is my Body Copy paragraph style and the word Term is its own character style.

Is there a way to create a table of contents where only the word Term shows up? In the TOC menu I seem to be only able to grab whole paragraph styles, but I can't apply a paragraph style to only one part of a line, which is why I went with the character style.

I hope I'm making sense. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a simple solution to this. But I'll show you a semi-automated solution which shouldn't be too cumbersome.

1. Make a duplicate of your "Body Copy" paragraph style (here called "Body Copy with Term") and apply it to every paragraph containing the "Term" character style using [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/137957/84899) method.
2. Create a character style for page numbers (here called "Page Number") and a character style for between entry and number (here called "Between").
3. Enter *Layout > Table of Contents*. Add the "Body Copy with Term" paragraph style to *Styles in Table of Contents > Include Paragraph Styles*. Set the *Page Number Style* to the "Page Number" character style and the *Between Entry and Number Style* to the "Between" character style. Press *OK*.

   [image]
4. Place the table of contents where you want it.
5. Select the text frame and enter *Edit > Find/Change*. Select the *GREP* tab. Enter `[^\r]` in the *Find what* field to search for everything except line breaks. Make sure the *Change to* field is empty so the found text is removed. Make sure *Search* is set to *Story*. Click the *Find Format* field and set *Character Style* to *[none]* to protect the "Term", "Between" and "Page Number" character styles.  Press *Change All*.

   [image]

Now the table of contents should only contain the terms, the page numbers and the stuff between.

If the table of contents is updated you will have to repeat point 5.

Comment: What’s the point of the _Between_ style here? Unless there’s something in the _Page number_ style that would make a tab (or other space) character unusable, why not just use that for both the spacers and the page numbers?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, I'm not sure I understand. Are you suggesting just using the *Page Number* style for the tab? It would work, but then you would loose the ability to style the tab. I'm just trying to transform the OP's special case to standard TOC behavior.

Comment: That’s what I meant, yes. Why would you normally _want_ to style a tab? It’s white space. Unless you specifically wanted to give the tab a yellow background or something like that, standard TOC behaviour would to me be to leave the tab unstyled. The extra character style doesn’t do any _harm_, of course, but it also doesn’t seem necessary for a standard TOC.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, I style that tab all the time! If I want to have some sort of line between the entry and the page number. I can use periods as a *leader* to get a dotted line, and then I mostly want to reduce the font size and add some tracking. I might also instead use an underline on the tab character.

Comment: I suppose YMMV on this. Personally I’ve only ever needed to use a leader in a TOC once (and I think I just did it directly in the paragraph style with no further formatting); the vast majority of TOCs I see (and make) do just fine with a simple space, so I’ve pretty much never needed it…

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, fair enough. But check out [the difference here](https://i.imgur.com/jVmpaJy.png). The second one looks far more sophisticated in my eyes.

Comment: I agree (though at least part of that is due to spacing, which can also just be done by including a space or two in the leader itself). But I’d tend to think no leader at all would look more sophisticated than either. :-p

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110757/discussion-between-wolff-and-janus-bahs-jacquet).